# Premake command line option to include a project

Tags: premake

So I have a Premake5 script to generate makefiles for my current project (a static library). It has a command line option called "with-sandbox". "sandbox" is a testing environment for the library. But the makefiles for it should only be created if the "with-sandbox" option is set. Thus, I made a filter which includes the Premake5 script of "sandbox" only when the option is set. But it seems like "include" is not effected by filters and so this does not work.

This is how my Premake5 script looks like for the main project:

```
newoption 
{
  trigger     = "with-sandbox",
  description = "Creates a sandbox testing environment"
}  


workspace "celer"

  project "celer"

    -- Project setup...

    filter "options:with-sandbox"

      include "tests/sandbox/"
```

And this is the Premake5 script for the "sandbox" project:

```
project "sandbox"

  -- Project setup...
```

I only want the "sandbox" stuff to exist if I want it to.
This is especially important when I use Visual Studio to port the library to Windows. I only want the "sandbox" project in my solution when it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do something like this

```
if _OPTIONS['with-sandbox'] then
 project "sandbox"
  ...
end
```

This way the project will be generated only if you pass the option